# Сочетание форм: образ жизни

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Вести (правильный) образ жизни" - правильное сочетание форм?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то в словаре сочетаемости ни в статье к слову образ,  ни в статье слова жизнь такого сочетания нет. Есть сочетание **вести (какую?) жизнь**. Но в речи действительно сложилось такое устойчивое сочетание - вести правильный (неправильный) образ жизни - с определенным значением: не пить, не курить, в меру работать. в меру отдыхать (желательно активно) и т.д. Возможно, оно зафиксировано каким-нибудь фразеологическим словарем. А возможно. нет.

Answer (score 0):

Все правильно. А что вас смущает?